# Why I can't find mod_dav_svn 1.6 in rpmforge?

Tags: svn, apache-2.2, centos, rpm

This is what I'm doing:

```
# yum --enablerepo=rpmforge list mod_dav_svn
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirrors.adams.net
 * base: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * extras: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
Available Packages
mod_dav_svn.x86_64             1.4.2-4.el5_3.1                     base
```

Why 1.4.2? Where is 1.6+?

Comment: Let me know if you find a package.  I've run into the exact same issue - presumably RPMForge has updated subversion but not updated mod_dav_svn to go with it - and I don't really see a solution.  There is another way to get subversion repositories served through SVNServe, but good luck trying to figure out SASL authentication (I've got an open question to that effect myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WANdisco](http://wandisco.com/?f=v) builds and tests the latest subversion binaries for a variety of platforms.

[http://wandisco.com/subversion/os/downloads](http://wandisco.com/subversion/os/downloads?f=v)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 1.6.x rpm for RHEL/CentOS, because nobody has built it. I was unable to find it using [rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/). [In CentOS 5.6 svn should be in 1.6.x](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/5.6_Release_Notes/ar01s11.html) (RHEL is in beta now).

`mod_dav_svn 1.4` is from your `Base` repository, not for `rpmforge`.